# Inter-nested struct type in C

Tags: c

I want to create 2 structs that are nested inside each other, but C won't allow this as when I define the first struct, the second struct is still not defined. How to solve this?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62uxC.png)

Comment: Code should be posted in the question as text.  Not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.  That being said, what would you expect the size of these structs to be?

Comment: please add the code to the question instead of linking to a picture to the code

Comment: Not possible in exactly that way, so please describe the problem you’re trying to solve with it.

Comment: If that were allowed and you had a `struct A a;` then that would have a member `a.b.a.b.a.b...` nested infinitely deep, which is of course not possible.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is add pointers to refer to the other structs :

```
struct y;

struct x {
  struct y * yy;
};

struct y {
  struct x * xx;
};
```